# Solve general quadratic systems, or find rational points on a Fano variety

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algorithms, systems-of-equations, computational-mathematics

Suppose we have $2n+1$ variables $\mathbf{x}=[x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2n}]^\mathsf{T}$ and $n$ symmetric matrices $(\mathbf{A}_1,\mathbf{A}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{A}_n)$ of dimension $(n+2)\times(n+2)$ and having coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. Define $\mathbf{u}={[1,x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]}^\mathsf{T}$, consider a system of $n$ quadratic equations
$$\begin{cases}\mathbf{u}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{A}_1\mathbf{u}=x_{n+1}^2\\\mathbf{u}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{A}_2\mathbf{u}=x_{n+2}^2\\\vdots\\\mathbf{u}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{A}_n\mathbf{u}=x_{2n}^2\end{cases}$$

It is known that the solutions $\mathbf{x}$ of the above system form a $n+1$ dimensional Fano variety, which is rationally connected and is thus supposed to have *a lot of* rational points in $\mathbb{Q}$ (or at least in a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$).

However, instead of knowing *how many* rational solutions there are, I'd rather want to **get some explicit rational solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$**, provided that there is any.

This can be done by applying a *generic* rational point finding algorithm, which is somewhat useful when $n$ is small. However, the complexity grows exponentially with $n$ so it quickly becomes infeasible even for moderately large $n$ (e.g., $n=100$). I can also try to compute a Gröbner basis, but the complexity is even worse (double exponential) so it is not likely to give any help either.

I would like to know that, apart from those completely generic methods (exhaustive search, or Gröbner basis), **is there any more efficient algorithm in finding rational solutions**, that can take advantage of the fact that the defining equations are limited to quadratic forms and the resulting variety is rationally connected/Fano?

I am aware that the degree alone will not play an essential role as it is possible to convert any system of polynomials into system of quadratics, but I believe that being rationally connected *really should mean something*, or otherwise it will seem really strange to me, that despite of the variety being supposed to have *a lot of* rational points, and the rational points on it possess *a particularly nice structure*, I will have *no way to do better in finding them than doing a generic search on a variety of generic type*.

The algorithm is not required to be deterministic, nor is it required to prove the existence or non-existence of a rational solution. It would be acceptable as long as when there does exist rational solutions, it has a non-trivial success rate to find one (by non-trivial success rate I mean a success rate guaranteed to be larger than a positive absolute constant independent of $n$). It is not required to have completely polynomial complexity either. It would be acceptable as long as it runs in sub-exponential time and is capable of handling reasonably large $n$ like $n=100$.

If such an algorithm (of finding rational points in sub-exponential time) does not exist, then at least I would like to know an algorithm that, given two rational solutions $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2$ of the above system, it **constructs an explicit rational curve** on the variety passing through those given points. Such a rational curve must exist (due to the very definition of being "rationally connected"), but instead of knowing "it must exist" I'd rather want to know an algorithm to **explicitly compute it**.

Does anyone has ideas on this? Any materials and references on **explicit computations in rationally connected/Fano varieties** are also much appreciated.

Comment: Also curious to see if something reasonable can be done here but I must protest you calling $n=100$ reasonable.